# How to run a rake task on jenkins with string parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, jenkins, rake, rake-task

I have the follow execute shell command:

`bundle exec rake ${RAKE_TASK[@]} RAILS_ENV=$ENVIRONMENT`

But it doesn't work when I need to run a task with parameters like that:

> bundle exec rake {namespace}:{task}['param1 param2']

how I could fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi everybody I got the answer:

$RAKE_TASK may have spaces in it depending on the parameters given to the rake task, which bash/jenkins don't deal with cleanly
So, we interpolate the variables into a double-quoted string, then eval the result.
This ensures that the spaces don't get messed up.

> bundle install
>
> echo $ENVIRONMENT
>
> eval "bundle exec rake $RAKE_TASK RAILS_ENV=$ENVIRONMENT"

It should be in the jenkins/job/configure page inside of **Execute shell** command